# What font is used in this Konis logo?

Tags: font-identification

I've tried whatthefont.com and the usual suspects but am having a hard time identifying this serif typeface;

[image: KONIS]

Comment: Probably the same as used here - http://www.thefirstchronicle.com/

Comment: It's quite similar to Argo by Anthony James: https://www.behance.net/gallery/15202845/ARGOE-Font I'd argue that the Argo font is a better font anyway? I guess it depends what you need it for…

Comment: Maybe you can ask here, they have a specific forum for font identification requests :http://www.dafont.com/forum/?f=1

Comment: @Ilan you're right it is the font used there, but that's an image. Lynton thank you for your suggestion unfortunately though I need this exact font.

Comment: @Jenna I had no time, so placed a link to image you can use for identification...

Comment: In that they are both didones, it's similar to Argo, but those are very different typefaces.

Comment: Also, that's a very bizarre 'S'. It' as if that was pulled from an entirely different typeface.

Comment: @DA01 "S" is the same on both images... so most probably it is part of the same font...

Comment: So, I'm hung up on that S. Notice how neither the S nor O hang below the baseline as they should in a properly designed typeface at this scale. I have a hunch this is either a somewhat sloppy freebie cobbled together from various other typefaces, or it's a highly customized logotype (with some questionable decisions made).

Comment: @Ilan ah! Didn't see your first link. Oof...the lowercase is even wonkier! Yea, I'm leaning towards this being a freebie font. I'd dig through Dafont.

Comment: If one of you would post it as an answer I'd be happy to mark it as right to keep the site tidy. I don't want to do it myself as it was your method that worked!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to all who helped.

I got there in the end, the answer was infact on dafont; [voor](http://www.dafont.com/voor.font?text=KONIS) is the font.

Here's a screenshot;

[image]

Comment: Boy, that's a strange font! Good find.

Answer (score 3):

It's your best friend -> [What The Font?](https://www.myfonts.com/WhatTheFont/results?ch%5B0%5D=K&ch%5B1%5D=O&ch%5B2%5D=N&ch%5B3%5D=I&ch%5B4%5D=S&wtfserver=wtf_b_41&id=000dd0df541d8b6d000d097600003046&glyphcount=5&imageid=0&x=37&y=52)

I'm betting it's the first one, and someone has modified it.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, but that was the result that I also got. I do think a font match is possible though as @Ilan found a site that uses the same font.

Comment: You know it's kind of harsh to simple downvote an answer because it no 100% correct. And I could be Linotype Didot just Modified. not saying my answer is right just point that out.

Comment: Hi @BurninLemons, just to let you know I didn't downvote your answer or any of the other answers here, I appreciate your effort to help me. I'm sorry if my comment seemed abrupt - there was only so long that I could spend online earlier. Just want to make sure that you know.

Comment: @Jenna No worries, I wasn't directing the comment at you, just in general. Just point out the fact that people seem to be abusing the voting systems a little bit.

Comment: No problem @BurninLemons I just didn't want it to seem like I was the culprit ;)

Answer (score -2):

parts of the font look very similar to http://www.fontsquirrel.com/fonts/abril-fatface this font.